# need help on pivot with conditional output

Tags: sql-server, pivot

hi need help on pivot with condition to output either decimal value or varchar value.

for sample i created a two temporary table: class_attendances and attendance_entry

```
create table #class_attendances(class_attendance_id int IDENTITY(1,1), class_attendance_date datetime, employee_name varchar(100), attendance_entry_id int)

create table #attendane_entry(attendance_id int IDENTITY(1,1), attendance_value varchar(20), attendance_value_dec decimal(8,2))
```

below is the insert script for attendance_entry table.

attendance_entry contain 3 columns with id, attendance_value (varchar) and attendance_value_desc which represent the decimal value of the attendance entry.

```
INSERT INTO #attendane_entry (attendance_value, attendance_value_dec) VALUES('1.00', 1.00)
INSERT INTO #attendane_entry (attendance_value, attendance_value_dec) VALUES('2.00', 2.00)
INSERT INTO #attendane_entry (attendance_value, attendance_value_dec) VALUES('3.00', 3.00)
INSERT INTO #attendane_entry (attendance_value, attendance_value_dec) VALUES('4.00', 4.00)
INSERT INTO #attendane_entry (attendance_value, attendance_value_dec) VALUES('5.00', 5.00)
INSERT INTO #attendane_entry (attendance_value, attendance_value_dec) VALUES('6.00', 6.00)
INSERT INTO #attendane_entry (attendance_value, attendance_value_dec) VALUES('7.00', 7.00)
INSERT INTO #attendane_entry (attendance_value, attendance_value_dec) VALUES('8.00', 8.00)
INSERT INTO #attendane_entry (attendance_value, attendance_value_dec) VALUES('Absent', 0.00)
INSERT INTO #attendane_entry (attendance_value, attendance_value_dec) VALUES('Holiday', 0.00)
INSERT INTO #attendane_entry (attendance_value, attendance_value_dec) VALUES('OFF', 0.00)
select * from #attendane_entry

attendance_id   attendance_value    attendance_value_dec
1               1.00                1.00
2               2.00                2.00
3               3.00                3.00
4               4.00                4.00
5               5.00                5.00
6               6.00                6.00
7               7.00                7.00
8               8.00                8.00
9               Absent              0.00
10              Holiday             0.00
11              OFF                 0.00
```

class_attendances table contain the attendance of employee with attendance_date and reference attendance_entry_id from attendance_entry

```
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 1, 'name 1',8)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 2, 'name 1',9)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 3, 'name 1',7)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 4, 'name 1',10)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 5, 'name 1',11)

INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 1, 'name 2',9)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 2, 'name 2',7)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 3, 'name 2',11)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 4, 'name 2',10)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 5, 'name 2',8)

INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 1, 'name 3',11)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 2, 'name 3',7)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 3, 'name 3',8)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 4, 'name 3',10)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 5, 'name 3',9)

INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 2, 'name 4',7)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 4, 'name 4',8)

INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 1, 'name 5',7)
INSERT INTO #class_attendances (class_attendance_date ,employee_name ,attendance_entry_id) VALUES (getdate() + 3, 'name 5',8)
```

i created a sample pivot script as shown below

```
-- create my base table
create table #base_table (class_attendance_date varchar(10), employee_name varchar(100), attendance_value varchar(20), attendance_value_dec decimal(8,2))
-- insert record to base table 
insert into #base_table (class_attendance_date, employee_name, attendance_value, attendance_value_dec)
SELECT       convert(varchar(10),#class_attendances.class_attendance_date, 101) as class_attendance_date, #class_attendances.employee_name, #attendane_entry.attendance_value, #attendane_entry.attendance_value_dec
FROM            #class_attendances INNER JOIN
                         #attendane_entry ON #class_attendances.attendance_entry_id = #attendane_entry.attendance_id
--select * from #base_table


DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @PivotSelectColumnNames AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @PivotColumnNames = N'';
SELECT @PivotColumnNames = @PivotColumnNames +  N', ' + QUOTENAME(class_attendance_date)
FROM( SELECT DISTINCT(class_attendance_date) FROM #base_table AS p GROUP BY class_attendance_date ) AS x;

SELECT @PivotSelectColumnNames = ISNULL(@PivotSelectColumnNames + ',','')    + 'ISNULL(' + QUOTENAME(class_attendance_date) + ', 0) AS '  + ' '+ QUOTENAME(class_attendance_date)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(class_attendance_date) FROM #base_table AS p GROUP BY class_attendance_date) AS y


SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'
SELECT employee_name, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + ' FROM (
SELECT employee_name,  attendance_value_dec, class_attendance_date
    FROM #base_table) AS j PIVOT (SUM(attendance_value_dec) FOR class_attendance_date in 
        ('+ STUFF(@PivotColumnNames, 1, 1, '') +')) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

the output of the pivot script shown below:

```
employee_name   06/21/2018  06/22/2018  06/23/2018  06/24/2018  06/25/2018
name 1          8.00        0.00        7.00        0.00        0.00
name 2          0.00        7.00        0.00        0.00        8.00
name 3          0.00        7.00        8.00        0.00        0.00
name 4          0.00        7.00        0.00        8.00        0.00
name 5          7.00        0.00        8.00        0.00        0.00
```

but i wanted to have an output like this.

```
employee_name   06/21/2018  06/22/2018  06/23/2018  06/24/2018  06/25/2018
name 1          8.00        Absent      7.00        Holiday     OFF
name 2          Absent      7.00        OFF         Holiday     8.00
name 3          OFF         7.00        8.00        Holiday     Absent
name 4          0.00        7.00        0.00        8.00        0.00
name 5          7.00        0.00        8.00        0.00        0.00
```

can somebody help me.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing the aggregate operation on the wrong column.

You have `attendance_value_dec` which is number you are currenty summing, and `attendance_value` the  which is the varchar you want to show.

Change your pivot query to do a `MAX(attendance_value)` instead.

```
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = N'
SELECT employee_name, ' + @PivotSelectColumnNames + ' FROM (
SELECT employee_name,  attendance_value, class_attendance_date
    FROM #base_table) AS j PIVOT (MAX(attendance_value) FOR class_attendance_date in 
        ('+ STUFF(@PivotColumnNames, 1, 1, '') +')) AS p;';
```

If you need to add together the attendances values for the same person on the same day, then make sure to do it on your base table first so you can do a `MAX()` and not need a `SUM()` at the pivot.